# How to calculate the divergence of stress matrix in polar coordinate system correctly

Tags: operators, coordinate-transformation

I calculate the divergence of stress matrix in polar coordinate system by the method of coordinate transformation as follows :

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Clear[Derivative]
ρ[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
φ[x_, y_] := ArcTan[y/x]
(((D[σρ[ρ[x, y], φ[x, y]], x] + 
       D[τ[ρ[x, y], φ[x, y]], 
        y]) /. {x -> ρ Cos[θ], 
      y -> ρ Sin[θ]}) // 
   FullSimplify[#, 0 < θ < Pi/2 && ρ > 0] &) // Expand
```

But the result I got is obviously different from the textbook. **I want to know how to calculate the divergence of the stress matrix in polar coordinates manually**.

**Supplementary information:**

Differential equation of equilibrium in polar coordinates calculated by $div(\sigma)+F=0$ in textbook :

[image]

**Related results calculated with Mathematica:**

I already know that the differential equilibrium equation in the rectangular coordinate system can be solved by the following methods:

```
(D[σx[x, y], x] + D[τxy[x, y], y] // FullSimplify) + Fx
(D[σy[x, y], y] + D[τxy[x, y], x] // FullSimplify) + Fy
```

And its result is equal to $div(\sigma)+F$.

```
Div[( {{σx[x, y], τxy[x, y]},{τxy[x, y], σy[x, y]}} ), {x, y}] + {Fx, Fy}
```

But I don't know how to calculate the divergence of `Div[{{σρ[r, φ], τ[r, φ]}, {τ[r, φ], σφ[r, φ]}}, {r, φ}, "Polar"]` in polar coordinates. I think it is necessary to know the specific calculation methods, otherwise, most users will be confused. I need detailed steps.

```
Div[({
   {σρ[r, φ], τ[r, φ]},
   {τ[r, φ], σφ[r, φ]}
  }), {r, φ}, "Polar"]
```

In other words, I want to know the detailed and concise mathematical process of calculating the divergence of the matrix function in polar coordinates ([Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3058010/740776) is a mathematical solution process, but it is too abstract, I want to reproduce it with Mathematica).

Comment: hi. It might be easier to answer this if you more clearly give the tensor itself. I can't figure out from your code where is the actual tensor you want its divergence. The divergence of matrix should be a vector. Each entry in this vector is the divergence of each column taken in order. So if you can take the divergence of a vector, then taking the divergence of matrix needs just a loop over the columns.

Comment: @Nasser In fact, I just want to know how to solve the differential equilibrium equation in polar coordinates in elasticity.

Comment: " I want to know how to calculate the divergence of stress matrix in polar coordinates manually." I'm voting to close this question because it's not a question about _Mathematica_.

Comment: @xzczd However, the calculation of divergence in polar coordinates is complex. I think it is necessary to know the specific calculation methods, otherwise, most users will be confused.

Comment: Then you should ask this in proper site like math.SE or physics.SE, or adjust your question to make it on-topic here, rather than ask it in such a careless way.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much for your suggestion. I would like to use Mathematica to list the concise and specific calculation process so that I can conveniently to use computers to calculate similar problems.

Comment: @xzczd The related answers did not satisfy me, and they lacked specific and complete details. So I added a description of the mathematics and asked a question again.

Comment: @xzczd I don't think there's anything wrong with the combination of MMA and mathematics, and you asked [a similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225423/how-is-grad-defined-for-array-particularly-in-non-cartesian-coordinates).

Comment: Actually, I ask that question partly to guide you how to ask such question in this site, but sadly you seem to learn nothing from it. As said above, the question can be made on-topic, but now it's not, all because you're asking it in a careless way. So long I've given you so much advice for improving your question(s), but you've ignored all of them. Then, the only thing I can give you is just a downvote.

Comment: @xzczd Ok, I have mastered the basic programming grammar. Now I mainly want to combine MMA with mathematical analysis and the after-school questions of professional courses, so I can only ask these questions. As for the details, I will gradually improve them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know nothing about differential geometry it is always safest to transform everything back to the Cartesian coordinate system since there everything is "nice".

In particular, you probably know that in the two-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system the divergence of a vector $\mathbf{F} = F_x \mathbf{e}_x + F_y \mathbf{e}_y$ (with unit normal vectors $\mathbf{e}_i$, $i = x,y$) is given by

$$ \mathrm{div}\, \mathbf{F} = \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}} F_x(x,y) + \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}} F_y(x,y) $$

You now want to compute the divergence of the **same** vector decomposed with respect to the polar coordinate system, i.e. $\mathbf{F} = F_\rho \mathbf{e}_\rho + F_\theta \mathbf{e}_\theta$ (with unit normal vectors $\mathbf{e}_i$, $i = \rho, \theta$).
You probably also know that the components of vectors are related by a rotation

$$
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
    F_x\\F_y 
  \end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
    \cos\theta & - \sin\theta\\ 
    \sin\theta & \cos\theta
  \end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
    F_\rho\\F_\theta 
  \end{matrix}
\right)
$$

or expressed in Cartesian coordinates

$$
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
    F_x\\F_y 
  \end{matrix}
\right)
=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
    x & -y \\
    y & x
  \end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
    F_\rho\\F_\theta 
  \end{matrix}
\right)
$$

The crucial thing to obverse now is that if you want to use the formula for the Cartesian coordinate system, you have to apply the chain rule. That is, the arguments in $F_i(\rho, \theta)$ are functions of $x$ and $y$. Explicitly you have

$$ F_i(\rho, \theta) = F_i\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \right) $$

With this you can "easily" derive the expression of the divergence in polar coordinates.

In Mathematica you can achieve this for instance as follows

```
vecPolar = {f\[Rho][\[Rho], \[Theta]], f\[Theta][\[Rho], \[Theta]]};
(* Rewrite the arguments of the components. This is *not* a change of \
basis. The components are still with respect to the polar coordinate \
system. *)
vecPolarInCartesian = 
  TransformedField[
     "Polar" -> "Cartesian", #, {\[Rho], \[Theta]} -> {x, y}] & /@ 
   vecPolar;
(* Alternative:
vecPolarInCartesian=vecPolar/.{\[Rho]\[Rule]Sqrt[x^2+y^2],\[Theta]\
\[Rule]ArcTan[y/x]} *)
(* Define the rotation matrix. *)
rot =
  CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
   "OrthonormalBasisRotation", {x, y}];
(* Alternative:
rot={{x/Sqrt[x^2+y^2],-(y/Sqrt[x^2+y^2])},{y/Sqrt[x^2+y^2],x/Sqrt[x^2+\
y^2]}}; *)
(* Change of basis. The new components are now with \
respect to the Cartesian basis *)

vecCartesian = rot.vecPolarInCartesian;
(* Compute divergence. This is coordinate independent! *)

divergenceInCartesian = Simplify@Div[vecCartesian, {x, y}];
(* Rewrite in polar coordinates. *)
divergenceInPolar = 
  TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
     divergenceInCartesian, {x, y} -> {\[Rho], \[Theta]}] // 
    Assuming[\[Rho] > 0, FullSimplify@#] & // # /. 
     ArcTan[Cos[\[Theta]_], Sin[\[Theta]_]] -> \[Theta] &;
(* Alternative:
divergenceInPolar=(divergenceInCartesian/.{x\[Rule]\[Rho] \
Cos[\[Theta]],y\[Rule]\[Rho] \
Sin[\[Theta]]})//Assuming[\[Rho]>0,FullSimplify@#]&//#/.ArcTan[Cos[\
\[Theta]_],Sin[\[Theta]_]]\[Rule]\[Theta]& *)
SameQ[divergenceInPolar,
  Div[vecPolar, {\[Rho], \[Theta]}, "Polar"]]
(* True *)
```

### Matrix divergence

The case for matrix divergence is completely analogous.

For a matrix

$$ \mathbf{M} = \sum_{i,j=x,y} M^{ij} \mathbf{e}_i \otimes \mathbf{e}_j $$

the components now transform as

$$
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
M_{xx} & M_{xy} \\
M_{yx} & M_{yy}
  \end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
\cos\theta & - \sin\theta\\ 
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
  \end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
M_{\rho\rho} & M_{\rho\theta} \\
M_{\theta\rho} & M_{\theta\theta}
  \end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
\cos\theta & - \sin\theta\\ 
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
  \end{matrix}
\right)^{\mathrm{T}}
$$
where $\mathrm{T}$ denotes transposition.

Note that when you compute

$$ \mathrm{div} \mathbf{M} $$
the result is a vector. As mentioned above, you know how to change basis vor vectors. Indeed, given a vector in the Cartesian basis we know

$$
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
F_x\\F_y 
  \end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
\cos\theta & - \sin\theta\\ 
\sin\theta & \cos\theta
  \end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
F_\rho\\F_\theta 
  \end{matrix}
\right)
$$

(the matrix is just the inverse of the one stated above).

In Mathematica you can cook this up as follows:

```
matPolar = {{f\[Rho]\[Rho][\[Rho], \[Theta]], 
    f\[Rho]\[Theta][\[Rho], \[Theta]]}, {f\[Theta]\[Rho][\[Rho], \
\[Theta]], f\[Theta]\[Theta][\[Rho], \[Theta]]}};
(* Rewrite the arguments of the components. This is *not* a change of \
basis. The components are still with respect to the polar coordinate \
system. *)
matPolarInCartesian = 
  Map[TransformedField[
       "Polar" -> 
        "Cartesian", #, {\[Rho], \[Theta]} -> {x, y}] &, #, {2}] &@
   matPolar;
(* Define the rotation matrix. *)
rotInCartesian =
  CoordinateTransformData["Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
   "OrthonormalBasisRotation", {x, y}];
rotInPolar = Map[
   TransformedField[
     "Cartesian" -> "Polar", #, {x, y} -> {\[Rho], \[Theta]}] &,
   rotInCartesian,
   {2}
   ];
(* Change of basis. The new components are now with respect to the \
Cartesian basis *)

matCartesian = 
  rotInCartesian.matPolarInCartesian.Transpose[rotInCartesian];
(* Compute divergence. This is with respect to the {x, y} basis. *)

divCartesianInCartesian = Simplify@Div[matCartesian, {x, y}];
(* Rewrite in terms of polar coordinates. This is *not* a change of \
bais! *)
divCartesianInPolar = 
  TransformedField[
     "Cartesian" -> "Polar", #, {x, y} -> {\[Rho], \[Theta]}] & /@ 
   divCartesianInCartesian;
(* Change of basis to polar coordinates. *)

divPolar = 
  Inverse[rotInPolar].divCartesianInPolar // 
    Assuming[\[Rho] > 0, FullSimplify@#] & // # /. 
     ArcTan[Cos[\[Theta]_], Sin[\[Theta]_]] -> \[Theta] &;
Union@Simplify@
  Thread[Equal[divPolar, Div[matPolar, {\[Rho], \[Theta]}, "Polar"]]]
(* {True} *)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, [my new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226134/how-to-calculate-the-divergence-of-a-function-matrix-in-polar-coordinates-in-det?noredirect=1#comment575402_226134) has been closed. I want to find the divergence of matrix functions, such as `Div[({
   {σρ[r, φ], τ[r, φ]},
   {τ[r, φ], σφ[r, φ]}
  }), {r, φ}, "Polar"]`. The divergence of matrix function needs to be considered as a whole, which is more complex than vector function.

Comment: @Ordinaryusers68 It is not too hard to generalize. You have to know how matrices transform under a change of basis. Also the result of a "matrix divergence" is a vector which you then need to change again back from Cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a great answer. It would be nice if I could write a little bit shorter, but that's enough for me.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have adopted your answer, but I still have some details that I don't understand. I'll ask again [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226372/how-to-calculate-divergence-in-polar-coordinate-system-with-concise-method). I hope you can take some time to have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But I don't understand **why** the rotation matrix takes the same parameter `θ` as the variable `θ` of the function matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
 f_{ρρ}(ρ,θ) &  f_{ρθ}(ρ,θ) \\
f_{θρ}(ρ,θ)  &f_{θθ}(ρ,θ)
\end{pmatrix}$.  **I need a concise explanation**.   If you can, I hope you can take the time to update your answers

Comment: @Ordinaryusers68 Sorry for the late reply, but I think that your question is out of the scope of this site. I would recommend that you have a look at the Wikipedia article [Tensors in curvilinear coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensors_in_curvilinear_coordinates).

Comment: It doesn't matter. Thank you very much for your reply. I will study that wiki page carefully.

Answer (score 1):

The result can be obtained by calculating the Kristol sign in polar coordinates under the nonholonomic physical frame (llc).

```
T = σrr*er\[TensorProduct]er + σrϕ*er\[TensorProduct]eϕ + σϕr*eϕ\[TensorProduct]er + σϕϕ*eϕ\[TensorProduct]eϕ;
div = Dt[#, r].er + Dt[#, ϕ].eϕ/r &;
rule1 = {Dt[er, r] -> 0, Dt[er, ϕ] -> eϕ, 
   Dt[eϕ, r] -> 0, Dt[eϕ, ϕ] -> -er};
rule2 = {er -> {1, 0}, eϕ -> {0, 1}};
(div[T] /. rule1 /. rule2)
```

Although the result of this code is correct, it does not clearly and concisely demonstrate the mathematical principle of seeking divergence in polar coordinates. I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica has built-ins.

So one path is

```
polarGrad[f_] := 
 Block[{r, th, grad, rot, assume}, 
  assume = CoordinateChartData["Polar", 
     "CoordinateRangeAssumptions"][{r, th}];
  rot = CoordinateTransformData["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
    "OrthonormalBasisRotation", {r, th}];
  grad = Grad[f[r, th], {r, th}, "Polar"];
  grad = CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Polar", 
    Transpose[rot].grad];
  Simplify[grad, assume]]

Assuming[V'[r] > 0, polarGrad[Function[{r, th}, V[r]]]]
```

> {V'[r], th}

```
polarGrad[Function[{r, th}, r Sin[th]]]
```

That is already answered to another question on stackexchange.com.

Following the given formula ()+=0:

```
Div[{f[r, θ], g[r, θ]}, {r, θ}, "Polar"]
```

[image: output of the built-in Div in polar plain coordinates]

with `σ[r, θ] = {f[r, θ], g[r, θ]}`

an example is already in the documentation of Div

```
Div[{r Sin[θ], -r Cos[θ]}, {r, θ}, "Polar"]
```

> 3 Sin[θ]

Mind the representation of the force F is `F_r e_r + F_Theta e_Theta`.
The polar unit vector are local and take away usually parts of the r and Theta dependence from the representation of the force in different coordinate systems.

The divergence can be calculated from rank 2 tensors in a similar fashion.

```
Div[{{x y, x y^2, x y^3}, {x^2 y, x^2 y^2, x^2 y^3}, {x^3 y, x^3 y^2, 
   x^3 y^3}}, {x, y, z}]
```

> {y + 2 x y, 2 x y + 2 x^2 y, 3 x^2 y + 2 x^3 y}

Since this question targets polar coordinates we calculate this task for a 2 x 2 matrix

```
{{x y, x y^2}, {x^2 y, x^2 y^2}}
```

transform the functions in the matrix elements with
x= r Sin[Theta]
y= r Cos[Theta]

```
{{r^2 Sin[Theta]Cos[Theta], r^3 Sin[Theta]Cos[Theta]^2}, {r^3 Sin[Theta^2]Cos[Theta], r^4 Sin[Theta]^2Cos[Theta]^2}}
```

Now apply the Div in polar coordinates to this matrix:

```
Div[{{r^2 Sin[Theta] Cos[Theta], 
   r^3 Sin[Theta] Cos[Theta]^2}, {r^3 Sin[Theta^2] Cos[Theta], 
   r^4 Sin[Theta]^2 Cos[Theta]^2}}, {r, θ}, "Polar"]
```

> {2 r Cos[Theta] Sin[Theta] + (
> r^2 Cos[Theta] Sin[Theta] - r^4 Cos[Theta]^2 Sin[Theta]^2)/r,
> 3 r^2 Cos[Theta] Sin[Theta^2] + (
> r^3 Cos[Theta]^2 Sin[Theta] + r^3 Cos[Theta] Sin[Theta^2])/r}

This has to be equal to the resulting matrix in cartesian coordinates.

```
Div[{{x y, x y^2}, {x^2 y, x^2 y^2}}, {x, y}]
```

> {y + 2 x y, 2 x y + 2 x^2 y}

This transformation to be applied makes use of the afore mention unit vector representation. Both are equal. {Sin[Theta],Cos[Theta]} for e_r and  {Cos[Theta],-Sin[Theta]} for e_Theta.

```
TransformedField[
  "Polar" -> 
   "Cartesian", {2 r Cos[θ] Sin[θ] + (r^2 Cos[θ] \
Sin[θ] - r^4 Cos[θ]^2 Sin[θ]^2)/r, 
   3 r^2 Cos[θ] Sin[θ^2] + (r^3 Cos[θ]^2 Sin[\
θ] + r^3 Cos[θ] Sin[θ^2])/
     r}, {r, θ} -> {x, y}] // FullSimplify
```

[image: calculation step intermediate]

This question is about path integrals. These are essential for the concept of the divergence:
[line-integration-given-tangent-vector](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/222064/line-integration-given-tangent-vector).

Mathematica does all its computations in an orthonormal basis. You simply need to specify what coordinate system you're working in. So for your example, you just multiply by {0, 0, 1}:

```
e[r_, θ_, ϕ_, t_] := (Sin[θ]/r)[Cos[r - t] - Sin[r - t]/r] {0, 0, 1}
```

Apparently this is a pure wave in vacuum, as the divergence is zero:

```
Div[e[r, θ, ϕ, t], {r, θ, ϕ}, "Spherical"]
```

> 0

Similarly, a pure Coulomb electric field would be

```
col[r_, θ_, ϕ_] := {1/r^2, 0, 0}
Div[col[r, θ, ϕ], {r, θ, ϕ}, "Spherical"]
```

> 0

I suggest you look at the tutorials tutorial/VectorAnalysis and tutorial/ChangingCoordinateSystems and the functions linked therefrom for more.

The built-in [`CoordinateTransformData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateTransformData.html) holds all the data of interest.

The built-in [`TransformedField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedField.html) is a nice tool to the tedious calculations' interest.

Polar coordinates have advantages if
a) the problem is two dimensional,
b) the symmetry is easily mappable[enter link description here](http://web.mit.edu/16.20/homepage/4_ElasticityBVP/ElasticityBVP_files/module_4_with_solutions.pdf) to this

```
Show[Table[
  PolarPlot[r, {θ, -π, π}], {r, 0.1, 1., 0.1}], 
 ListPolarPlot[Table[Table[{m π/3, n/125}, {n, 125}], {m, 0, 5}]]]
```

[image]

These are interesting if

```
CoordinateTransformData[
 "Cartesian" -> "Polar", "MappingJacobianDeterminant", {x, y}]

1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
```

is advantageous and not a problem.

To work on a fruitful common basis with the formulas for plane stress I suggest this [ElasticityBVP](http://web.mit.edu/16.20/homepage/4_ElasticityBVP/ElasticityBVP_files/module_4_with_solutions.pdf).