# Issue with the Laplacian in Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: vector-calculus

I am using Mathematica 12.1.1 and am unable to get the correct result for a simple laplacian in 3D Cylindrical Coordinates. I want to reproduce the following result on Mathematica:[image: Desired result]

But, I am only getting the second term from the above result. Here's the code I am using:

```
APotential = {A0/(k r) Sin[k z - ω t], 0, 0};

Laplacian[APotential, {r, θ, z}, "Cylindrical"]

(* OUTPUT IS: {-((A0 k Sin[k z-t ω])/r),0,0} *)
```

Is this because of a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, you made a typo. In the definition of the pot. the angle is called: t, but in the Laplacian the angle is called theta.

Comment: @DanielHuber I believe `t` is time, not the angle theta.

Comment: Yup, as @BillWatts said, t refers to time, while θ is the azimuth angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Laplacian takes a scalar argument, so if you want to take the Laplacian of a vector you need to do each component separately.  This works:

```
Ar[r_, θ_, z_] = A0/(k r) Sin[k z - ω t]

Laplacian[Ar[r, θ, z], {r, θ, z}, "Cylindrical"]
(*(A0 Sin[k z - t ω])/(k r^3) - (A0 k Sin[k z - t ω])/r*)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! So, if Aθ and Az were non zero as well, would I have to calculate them separately and then add the final results?

Comment: To be honest, I've never seen them added together, and I'm not sure what that would be physically.  Assigning the pieces to vector components would be OK if you really need them to form a vector.

Comment: Ah alright. Thank you again

Comment: You are welcome.  But I am puzzled at Mathematica's answer to your code.  It seems to me that if it cannot calculate the Laplacian for a vector, it should return unevaluated, rather than return the wrong answer.

Comment: @SiddharthChaini As to how _Mathematica_ deals with `Laplacian` of a vector, you may want to read this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225423/1871

Answer (score 1):

For general vector field `{f[r, t, z], g[r, t, z], h[r, t, z]}`, the  Laplacian is

```
Laplacian[{f[r, t, z], g[r, t, z], h[r, t, z]}, {r, t, z}, 
  "Cylindrical"] // Expand
```

So we write

```
APotential = {A0/(k r) Sin[k z - ω t], 0, 0};
Laplacian[APotential, {r, t, z}, "Cylindrical"] // Expand
```

Comment: Hi, actually the azimuth angle is θ, while t refers to time. So the basis will be {r, θ, z} and not {r, t, z}. That still gives an error. However, Bill's answer worked well instead. Thank you nevertheless.